# comparing two strings with a different format but same meaning

Tags: sql

Is there a way i can use to compare the two strings `12 AD E4 9F` and `12:ad:E4:9f`  and get a result which says they are similar. There are stored in different tables and i would like to  create a view by joining the tables using strings as a joining criteria

Comment: You can reduce them to a minimal form. For example, replace all `:` with nothing and perform uppercase.

Comment: Are the strings always in these 2 formats? BTW, what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: What DB Engine are you using?  (SQL Server, MySQL, etc)

Comment: this problem is nonexistent: both strings have the same format, which is `/([0-9a-f]{2}[ :]){3}[0-9a-f]{2}/i` (I'm still a novice at regexp so correct me if I'm wrong)

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the second string to upper case and then remove all ' ' and ':' before comparing the strings

Select UPPER(REPLACE('12:ad:E4:9f',':',' ') from dual;

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to eliminate the characters before doing the comparison:

```
where replace(col1, ' ', '') = replace(col2, ':', '')
```

Or do the replacement of one separator to the other:

```
where replace(col1, ' ', ':') = col2
```

In general, SQL is case-insensitive in string comparisons, unless you explicitly set it to be case-sensitive.  If you have case sensitivity one, then wrap the above in `lower()` or `upper()`.  The functions `replace()`, `upper()`, and `lower()` are available in most databases (although some might have slightly different names).

Answer (score 0):

Try this way for tsql.
You should use `replace` and `upper` function. In below example col2 is `12:ad:E4:9f`

```
select *
from tab1 t1
join tab2 t2 on upper(t1.col1) = upper(REPLACE((t2.col2,':',''))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(ProductDescription)), ':', '')
SELECT UPPER(ProductDescription)
```

then compare..